# Building native extensions error in installing ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, environment-variables, travis-ci

I installed a ruby version as below

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448-dev
```

and when i checked version as below

```
$ ruby -v

ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]
```

But when i tried to install travis like below

```
$ gem install travis

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing travis:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `initialize': Permission denied - /home/user/.travis/travis.sh (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `open'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1371:in `block in copy_file'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `open'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1370:in `copy_file'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:477:in `copy_file'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:396:in `block in cp'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1515:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1529:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1513:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:395:in `cp'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/travis-1.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/travis-1.5.2/completion/gem_make.out
```

So how to avoid the above `native extensions` error and install the `travis` succesfully using `gem`

**Edit**

When i tried the command by including `sudo` as below

```
sudo gem install travis
```

I am getting the below message as success

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed travis-1.5.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for travis-1.5.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for travis-1.5.2...
```

And now what all i am trying to do is to set up `environ` variables on `travis`
and hence i tried the following command

```
$ travis encrypt -r travis_uname/app_name EMAIL_HOST_KEY=key_value
```

and getting the below wierd error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find travis (>= 0) amongst [addressable-2.3.5, backports-3.3.3, bundler-1.3.5, bundler-unload-1.0.1, coderay-1.0.9, ethon-0.6.0, faraday-0.8.8, faraday_middleware-0.9.0, ffi-1.9.0, gh-0.11.3, highline-1.6.19, launchy-2.3.0, method_source-0.8.2, mime-types-1.24, multi_json-1.7.9, multipart-post-1.2.0, net-http-persistent-2.9, net-http-pipeline-1.0.1, netrc-0.7.7, pry-0.9.12.2, pusher-client-0.3.1, rake-10.1.0, ruby-hmac-0.4.0, rubygems-bundler-1.2.2, rubygems-update-2.0.7, rvm-1.11.3.8, slop-3.4.6, typhoeus-0.6.4, websocket-1.0.7, websocket-native-1.0.0] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/travis:18
```

So finally how to avoid above error and make the above travis command work successfully ?

Comment: You installed `travis` in ruby 1.9.3 and then switched to ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, set the Ruby version you are using as a default

```
rvm use --default ruby-1.9.3-p448-dev
```

and uninstall the gem previously installed with `sudo`

```
sudo gem uninstall travis
```

this makes sure that all your commands are using the same Ruby version and your machine is clean again. Now to your installation problem. This error

```
Permission denied - /home/user/.travis/travis.sh (Errno::EACCES)
```

shows you, that the installer tried to access `/home/user/.travis` but wasn't able to do so due to a lack of user permissions. This means you need to make sure that the folder belongs to you and is writeable

```
chown -R `whoami` ~/.travis
chmod -R u+wx ~/.travis
```

Now go ahead and try to re-install:

```
gem install travis
```

and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i had executed all the above commands, and when i tried `gem install travis` still the same error `permission denied`, but when i tried `sudo gem install travis' its telling that `i gem installed` but travis command is not working

Comment: The reason that it works when you use `sudo` is that the root user has all permissions and thus can write everywhere. After that it probably does not work because the root user probably uses a different ruby version. After all, `sudo` is **not** the way to go! Installation of a gem shoud not require root permissions at all! Try this: `sudo gem uninstall travis` then again use the `chown` and `chmod` commands from above, but use the `-R` flag (see edited answer). Then try `gem install travis` again, without `sudo`! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Installing the `-dev` packages fixed it for me...

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Comment: I had the error message `install build tools  (or similar) and followed up at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29317694/873282, which provided the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes when you install some gems with sudo and other not. 
Ideally you should never sudo for the gem install.
So if you have several gems owned by root and you want to remove the ruby installation and the related gems, run this command:

`sudo rvm remove ruby-2.0.0-p353 --gems`

rvm remove is the preferred way of removing rubies from rvm. By default, not only will it remove the ruby and it's source files, it will also get rid of aliases, wrappers, environments and any associated binaries - in other words, it cleans up most of the install.

The --gems flag will get rid of all associated gemsets.

The you should reinstall your ruby version with:

`rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353`

and bundle install again.