# How to use gem to install Rails on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

The error message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20150328-1540-hff2f0.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.1
  --help
  --clean
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
  from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
  from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
  from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:621:in `with_cflags'
  from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
  from extconf.rb:337:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Configurations:

1. Ubuntu 14.10 (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-23-generic x86_64)
2. gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1
3. ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Answer (score 230, accepted):

After upgrading to Rails 4.2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04  using RVM I needed to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

Full stacktrace: http://ruby-on-rails-eq8.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/solving-ubuntu-1404-ruby-c-dependancy.html

Comment: MacKinley Smith, than you for the thought, but sorry, I guess "no". The original answer by shivam was for a problem years ago and was a valid answer. By pure coincidence the stack trace of the original question was similar when I was googling for a solution of my problem/answer and this was the top hit in Google. That's why I stick the answer here. So I'm glad my answer helps, but I don't want anyone loose their points for sake of it.

Answer (score 57):

You seem to be missing some Ruby requirement. If you are using RVM, try:

```
rvm requirements
```

to get the list of dependencies and install them manually.

Otherwise, install the known basic requirements directly using:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libxml2-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool
```

Comment: I don't use rvm, but the second solution worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: the apt-get command does not work on Fedora take a look at my answer below

Comment: Doesn't work, still fail with /home/peng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.

Comment: @tribbloid Same here. Could you resolve the issue meanwhile?

Comment: same with rbenv.. needed build essentials

Comment: The second one solved it for me (not sure which package..)

Answer (score 7):

You get this error because the development dependencies for Ruby are missing.

I suggest that you install and use RVM to solve this, check the official and updated instructions here https://rvm.io/rvm/install

At the time when I answer this question I followed these steps:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys
409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

If you get this warning

```
  * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/home/mao/.bash_profile':

  source ~/.profile
```

execute this command:

```
echo source ~/.profile >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, reload/apply the bash_profile that you just updated by executing this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Finally run this to install the requirements:

```
rvm requirements
```

This should work for any Linux distribution like Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian, Redhat, Slackware.

Comment: `"\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash'` is one of several options for installing RVM. Rather than follow this little excerpt from RVM's documentation here, read and follow [the installation instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) on RVM's site. On the surface RVM is easy to install, but we repeatedly get questions from people who didn't follow every debugging step when something goes wrong, and that page covers it all.

Comment: @theTinMan I have updated my answer to mention the RVm Install page as the updated way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For Centos 7, Redhat 7 :

```
yum -y install gcc ruby-dev
```

Comment: This also works on some debian variants. (apt-get install ruby-dev) Worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can install build-essential to setup devtools in ubuntu:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```