# Downloading rails - C won't compile

Tags: c, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to download rails and have gone through every solution I can find. I have redownloaded Xcode (7.0 beta) and have installed command line tools separately, including running: 
    xcode-select --install
which seems to work for most people with the same problem. I'm think I may have corrupted C header files.

```
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Would massively appreciate any help!

The full error code:

```
XXX-MacBook-Pro-2:~ XXX$ gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150923-10275-18xpyzg.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--help
--clean
/Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
from extconf.rb:337:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317640/gem-install-rails-fails-on-ubuntu

Comment: Homebrew or one of the other OS X package managers takes most of the pain out of installing open source on Mac.

Comment: Can you add contents of `mkmf.log`? Also are you running `homebrew`? If so, what's the output of `brew list | grep libxml2`?

Comment: Is it `nokogiri` that failed? That gem has [special problems on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643153/error-to-install-nokogiri-on-osx-10-9-maverick).

Comment: *"Check the mkmf.log file for more details."*

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue from past two weeks while trying to run a rails 3 version application.

**The issue is that your rvm/rbenv is not using the C compiler.**

**Use this command for rvm to take compatible C compiler**

```
CC=gcc rvm install-version
```

So if you are using Ruby 1.9.3, use it this way

```
CC=gcc rvm install-1.9.3
```

**Use this command every time you are not able to bundle install or anything.**
This thing is working on El Capitan, rails 3.2.16, ruby 1.9.3, mysql 5.7
Hopefully, It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line indicates it's not a Rails problem but a problem with nokogiri.

```
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
```

nokogiri has problems installing on OS X. Try [one of the solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19807558/14660).

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like it's a nokogiri problem as gem install nokogiri runs up errors (and this is in line with all the stack exchange answers I've come across - I've tried about 20 of them and spent a few hours on this).

Where do I find the mkmf.log file?

These are what I have in gem:

```
activesupport-4.2.4         nokogiri-1.6.6.2
i18n-0.7.0              nokogiri-1.6.7.rc3
mini_portile-0.5.3          rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
mini_portile-0.6.2          thread_safe-0.3.5
mini_portile-0.7.0.rc4          tree-0.2.1
minitest-5.8.1              tzinfo-1.2.2
nokogiri-1.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on Ubuntu 14.04:

> sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev

After that you should be able to proceed with `bundle install`.