# switching from pg gem to mysql, causing error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

My app was using `pg gem` but I faced some issues so I switched from `pg` to `mysql` but when I run `bundle` it cause error.

My `gem file`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.13'

# Use pg as the database for Active Record
# gem 'pg'
gem 'mysql2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# for user authentication
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2'

# Use materialize css
gem 'materialize-sass'
gem 'material_icons'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'


#For authorization
gem 'the_role'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

Here is my log:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 0.3.45
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.5
Using mime-types 2.6.2
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.4
Using arel 4.0.2
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using bcrypt 3.1.10
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using sass 3.4.18
Using bundler 1.11.2
Using byebug 8.2.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using tilt 2.0.1
Installing mysql2 0.4.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160116-12648-1cquvr6.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1060:in `block in have_header'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
    from /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1059:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails4/gems/mysql2-0.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails4/extensions/x86-linux/2.2.0/mysql2-0.4.2/gem_make.out
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using temple 0.7.6
Using activesupport 4.0.13
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.3
Using sprockets 3.3.5
Using mail 2.6.3
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.1.2
Using uglifier 2.7.2
Using better_errors 2.1.1
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using materialize-sass 0.97.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using haml 4.0.7
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am not sure what is the problem. Could any one can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2?

Comment: Make sure you changed the config/database.yml and have installed mysql and started the server

Comment: Looks like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317640/gem-install-rails-fails-on-ubuntu