# Not able to install gems "mysql2, mariadb 10.1" in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mariadb, mysql2, ubuntu-16.04

I have working mariadb 10.1 server.
I install ruby 2.3.0 on ubuntu 16.04.
I install libmariadbd-dev and libmariadbclient-dev.
When I try "gem install mysql2", then a recive message:

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160615-5183-kj9yds.rb extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/gem_make.out
```

And I can`t find how to build this gem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gem install mysql fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795309/gem-install-mysql-fail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gem install rails fails on ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317640/gem-install-rails-fails-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem in this situation need 3 packets.

```
sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev libssl-dev libcrypto++-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for mac but you need to change the path:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

intall mariadb 10.1 andnecesaary ssl packages or maybe this are not needed
then check the path to the libraries and the tinal folders have the same name:

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb@10.1/10.1.29/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

or without the ssl path

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb@10.1/10.1.29/bin/mysql_config
```

or directly the gem, but if you come ffrom mysql is better to do it with bundle

```
gem install mysql2 -v 'x.y.z' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb@10.1/10.1.29/bin/mysql_config
```

and finally

```
bundle install
```